# Angular ui-grid custom row template stopped row background color selection

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I've implemented the following row template on my ui-grid so I can get a double-click functionality up and running:

```
                function rowTemplate() {
                    return '<div ng-dblclick="grid.appScope.rowDblClick(row)" >' +
                                '  <div ng-style="{ \’cursor\’: row.cursor }" ng-repeat="(colRenderIndex, col) in colContainer.renderedColumns track by col.colDef.name" class="ui-grid-cell" ng-class="{ \'ui-grid-row-header-cell\': col.isRowHeader }"  ui-grid-cell></div>' +
                                '</div>';
                }
```

The double-click event works great on the ui-grid, however, I've lost the change in the row background color when a row is single-clicked.  I'm thinking it has something to do with the row template, but I'm unsure what to add to the template to allow for the background color change while still keeping the double-click event functionality.

Comment: Well you've added a new DIV surrounding what used to be a row. So I would guess that your new DIV becomes the new row. If you look in the ui-grid code you can see the viewport does things to the ROW to change the class to be selected (I'm assuming that is what you are talking about), so i would guess it is affecting the wrong div and therefore not showing up. I would suggest rather than wrapping the ui-grid-row with your own div that you just add your dblclick to the existing div and see if that works.

Comment: I moved the ng-dblclick event call into the same div line as the rest of the template and it works!  I'm getting a row highlight while keeping the double-click event functionality!  Thanks for the suggestion Scott!